# Order of evaluation for summing over integers

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In Fourier analysis, how should I interpret sums of the form
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n?$$
Is it
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{|n| < N} a_n$$
or
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n?$$
When do I not have to care about the order of summation?

Comment: I would use the latter interpretation.

Comment: I have most often seen the former used in discussion above convergence of Fourier series (for example as seen here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series).

Comment: Note that summation order is irrelevant if and only if either $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \max[a_n,0] < \infty$ or $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \min[a_n,0] > -\infty$. (This allows the sum to be $\infty$ or $-\infty$).  If you want to ensure a finite sum that is independent of order, then you need $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |a_n| < \infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is sometimes called the principal value since it is similar to the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) for sums. The second is the analog of the standard convergence of integrals. In any case, describing the kind of convergence is best.

The sum
$$
\pi\cot(\pi z)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{k+z}
$$
requires the principal value sum to converge, but it is often written as above.