# Summation containing $\pi$ gives an expression containing $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponential-function, pi

This is an interesting relation between $\pi$ and $e$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(k\pi)^2+1}=\frac{1}{\pi^2+1}+\frac{1}{4\pi^2+1}+\frac{1}{9\pi^2+1}+\frac{1}{16\pi^2+1}+\dots=\frac{1}{e^2-1}$$

I tried to prove it using Fourier series expansion, but I could not. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Poisson summation formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [the result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) that
$$
\mathrm{PV}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{x+k}=\pi\cot{\pi x}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{1+k^2\pi^2}
&=\frac{i}{2\pi}\mathrm{PV}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{i/\pi+k}-\frac12\\
&=\frac{i}{2\pi}\pi\cot\left(\pi\frac{i}\pi\right)-\frac12\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\coth(1)-\frac12\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{e^2-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Two different approaches—I love it!

Comment: That first formula holds only if you interpret the left side as the "principal value" of the sum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: indeed (and this is mentioned in the cited link). However, for conditionally convergent series, we do assume a certain order with $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty$. So perhaps it would be better to write $\sum\limits_{|n|=0}^\infty$ instead of $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: Yes, it's mentioned in the link. But it should be mentioned in your answer.

Comment: And it was as soon as I posted my comment (as per [my own recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2073968)). Oops, I missed that there were two instances.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the expansion
$$\coth x=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{n^2\pi^2+x^2}$$

Comment: OK, but how do you get that expansion?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I suppose you just have to be familiar with it. Deriving that is a whole separate matter

Comment: @GerryMyerson see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem this is Mittag-Leffler's theorem for coth.

Comment: haha :) why downvote?

Comment: @Nosrati I didn't downvote, but wanted to say that Mittag-Leffler is not enough to prove this identity. There are infinitely many meromorphic functions with the same expansions at every pole. It is far from clear that the sum you write gives $\coth$

Comment: @Nosrati It is. I am just adressing your comment regarding how to get the expansion.

Comment: @Wojowu thank you :)